# for loop that increases the value of a variable inside the loop based on a variable outside of it

Tags: php, laravel

I have a for loop that loops based on the variable `$total`. I want the variable `$skip` to increment by 6 (based on `$val1`) every time it loops. It should display like `6 12 18 24` cause it loops 4 times since we started with 0.

```
$val1 = 6;
$total = 20 / $val1;
    
for ($x = 0; $x <= $total; $x++) {
    $skip = 0;    //Increase every loop based on $val1
    echo "$skip" ;
}
```

Do I need to add another for loop inside the loop to increment the `$skip` or is there a function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value of $val1 to $skip will be ok. No need to have another loop.

```
<?php
$var1 = 6;
$total = 4;
    $skip=0;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $total; $x++) {
     
//Increase every loop based on $val1 below
   $skip = $skip+ $var1;    

        echo $skip. " "  ;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I guess this would work on php only but it generate Undefined variable: skip on laravel. sorry forgot to put laravel on the tag. willl update my question

Comment: oh yeah just figured it out too. i'm so dumb. cant believe i forgot about this things. Thanks

Comment: done. just waiting for the cooldown timer